# python asyncio run_in_executor never done

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio, python-3.10

I running the following code in `python 3.10.12`. There is a sync function `fetch_data`, which should return `1` immediately. And in `main` function, a CPU-bound task like `sum(i for i in range(int(1e6)))` which cost 4~5s.

```py
import asyncio

def fetch_data():
    print("done")
    return 1

async def main():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    task = loop.run_in_executor(None, fetch_data)
    sum(i for i in range(int(1e6)))
    print(task.done())

asyncio.run(main())
```

The output I expected is

```
done
True
```

But what I got is

```
done
False
```

The `fetch_data` seems never done, but when I insert `await asyncio.sleep(0)` before `print(task.done())`, the output is what I expected.

```py
import asyncio

def fetch_data():
    print("done")
    return 1

async def main():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    task = loop.run_in_executor(None, fetch_data)
    sum(i for i in range(int(1e6)))
    await asyncio.sleep(0) # After sleep(0), the output is as expected.
    print(task.done())

asyncio.run(main())
```

Why is this happening? What should I do to achieve what I needed without `asyncio.sleep(0)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's happening because you don't give the executor a change to process it's tasks. With `await asyncio.sleep(0)` you interrupt your `main()` function and executor process the tasks and the result is as expected.

If `asyncio.sleep` is problem, you can use other executor:

```py
import asyncio
import concurrent.futures


def fetch_data():
    print("done", flush=True)
    print()
    return 1


async def main():
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=2) as executor:
        task = executor.submit(fetch_data)
        sum(i for i in range(int(1e8)))
        print(task.done())


asyncio.run(main())
```

Prints:

```
done

True
```

Answer (score 0):

Only one small change: In your second listing, replace `asyncio.sleep(0)` with `task`.

```
import asyncio

def fetch_data():
    print("done")
    return 1

async def main():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    task = loop.run_in_executor(None, fetch_data)
    sum(i for i in range(int(1e6)))
    await task
    print(task.done())

asyncio.run(main())
```

The `run_in_executor` function creates a second thread, where `fetch_data` executes.  In simple terms, the main function continues while fetch_data runs in another thread.  [I'm ignoring for the moment all the issues related to Python thread-based concurrency.]  Your main function doesn't know when the executor finishes - it doesn't even know when the new thread starts.

If you want the main thread to wait until the executor is finished, and it seems like that is what you want, all you have to do is wait for it somehow.  You are right that asyncio.sleep(0) is a weird way to do that, since that function knows nothing about the task itself.  It happens to work in your case because `fetch_data` is very fast, so any sort of wait in the main thread is likely to work.

What's guaranteed to work is `await task`, which suspends the main thread (Task) right there until `task` is finished. It also makes your code easier to understand since it makes your intentions clear.